# How can I save relations from request body in nodejs + mongoose application?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 2 models, with Category->Products relation

In a web form, I create a new product, choosing a category object. Form sends the category id in the request body. This is my code to save the product:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
 var product = new Product(req.body)
  product.save(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        req.flash('success', 'Successfully created product!')
        return res.redirect('back')
      }
      res.render('products/new', {
        title: 'New Product',
        product: product,
        errors: utils.errors(err.errors || err)
      })
  })
}
```

All are ok here. But what I need is, adding this product to the "products" field of categories.

What is the best way to do this?